# How to SlideUp div when clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slideup

I have the following simple demo here: https://tinker.io/8e585/1. *I have attached code below.*

Initially, the contents of both 'Test 1' & 'Test 2' are closed.

However, when clicked, they open. I would like it, if *when* one is open and then clicked it closes. So, **if open AND clicked = close.** Is this possible?

Many thanks for any helpers with this :-)

..

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid_4">    
    <h2 style="margin-bottom:4px"><a href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes6');" style="color:#455560!important;">Test 1</a></h2>
    <div class="newboxes2" id="newboxes6">
        <p>bla 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_4">    
    <h2 style="margin-bottom:4px"><a href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes7');" style="color:#455560!important;">Test 2</a></h2>
    <div class="newboxes2" id="newboxes7">
        <p>bla 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.newboxes2 {display:none}
```

**jQuery**

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes2').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
                jQuery(this).parent('.grid_4').children().find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');
               $(this).slideDown(200);
          }
          else {
                jQuery(this).parent('.grid_4').children().find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
               $(this).slideUp(600);
          }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a class to do it:

https://tinker.io/8e585/12

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes2').each(function(index) {
          if (this.id == thechosenone) {
                if($(this).is('.active') )
                   $(this).removeClass('active').slideUp(600);
              else 
              $(this).addClass('active').slideDown(200);
          }
          else              
               $(this).removeClass('active').slideUp(600);

         if($(this).is('.active') )
             jQuery(this).parent('.grid_4').children().find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');
         else
             jQuery(this).parent('.grid_4').children().find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
     });
}
```

Comment: That's clever thinking. The demo works perfectly. Many thanks for taking the time to read my question and give an accurate answer. Going to green tick it and then learn from this :-D

Comment: definitly an option. easier to look up the css property (if set to 'none' slideDown otherwise slideUp). but see my answer for a lot easier code

Comment: Hey, @roasted. The only issue here is that the children image no longer swaps. Any ideas?

Comment: In your sample, i cannot see any image. Could you post the relevant html code, updating your tinker.

Comment: Thanks. Will try. Sorry for the confusion in my initial post. I messed up. BRB

Answer (score 0):

everything should be a lot easier then you think. you should remove your inline javascript event-handler. and use the jquery-toggle-mechanism:

then your javascript code could become as short as this:

```
$('.grid_4').bind('click', function () {
  $(this).find('.newboxes2').slideToggle(200);
});
```

see the updated tinker for an example: https://tinker.io/8e585/4

if you want your slideDown to be faster (200) than your slideUp (600), you could lookup the current display property:

```
var duration, $newboxes2;
$('.grid_4').bind('click', function () {
  $newboxes2 = $(this).find('.newboxes2');
  duration = $newboxes2.css('display') === 'none' ? 200 : 600;
  $(this).find('.newboxes2').slideToggle(duration);
});
```

tinker thats working here: https://tinker.io/8e585/5

code with your imageswap. this code could even be 1 or 2 lines shorter (the if-else), but i leave it like that, to make it easier to read for you:

```
var duration, $newboxes2, imgSrc, imgBase = '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/';

$('.grid_4').bind('click', function () {
  $newboxes2 = $(this).find('.newboxes2');
  if ($newboxes2.css('display') === 'none') {
    duration = 200;
    imgSrc = imgBase + 'image_corner_btn_onstate.png';
  } else {
    duration = 600;
    imgSrc = imgBase + 'image_corner_btn_offstate.png';
  }
  $(this).find('img.small').attr('src', imgSrc);
  $(this).find('.newboxes2').slideToggle(duration);
});
```

see tinker: https://tinker.io/8e585/13

Comment: many thanks for your answer. unfortunately this example doesn't keep my img code in there `jQuery(this).parent('.grid_4').children().find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an accordion: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ alternatively, you could use the Javascript below (remove the inline Javascript you have in your HTML and just use '#'):

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
  var links =  $('.grid_4 h2:first-child a');
  links.addClass('closed');
  links.click(function() {    
   var $this = $(this);

   links.each(function() {
     var curLink = $(this);
     if(curLink !== $this) {
       curLink.parents('.grid_4').find('.newboxes2').slideUp(600, function({curLink.addClass('closed');});
       curLink.parents('.grid_4').find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
        }
  });

    if($this.hasClass('closed')) {
        $this.parents('.grid_4').find('.newboxes2').slideDown(200, function() {$this.removeClass('closed');});
        $this.parents('.grid_4').find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');
    } else {
        $this.parents('.grid_4').find('.newboxes2').slideUp(600, function() {$this.addClass('closed');});
        $this.parents('.grid_4').find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
    }

});
});
})(jQuery);
```